# @PathVariable and @RequestParam in one query

Tags: spring, rest

I have a request which doesn't work

```
http://localhost:8070/promo/lock/1?reason=CONSUMED
```

There is my config of an endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(name = SERVICE_URL + "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void unlock(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam(value = "reason") UnlockReason reason, @PathVariable Long id)
```

I get the exception

> rg.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing
>   URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues is your annotation mappings:

- **`@RequestMapping`** : It should take the URI path as '*path*' and not as name.

  ```
  @RequestMapping(path = SERVICE_URL + "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  ```
- **`@PathVariable`** : Should have the path param name, as the default value is `""`.

  ```
  public void unlock(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam(value = "reason") UnlockReason reason, @PathVariable("id") Long id
  ```

Comment: I believe Spring 4 deduces the `@PathVariable` name from method parameter name via `ParameterNameDiscoverer`, so no need for that.

Comment: It is worth noting that path is alias for value, so they are equivalent. Also I believe that @IlyaNovoseltsev is correct, placeholder name is expected by default for the path variable parameter name (e.g. mapping `"/{id}"` and `@PathVariable String id` should work.

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev I'm not aware about Spring 4 yet, but thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the method argument matches the name of the path variable exactly, then it can be simplified by using @PathVariable with no value:
 So this is correct :

```
public void unlock(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam(value = "reason") UnlockReason reason, @PathVariable Long id)
```

If you want to give it some other name, you need to do this by :

```
public void unlock(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam(value = "reason") UnlockReason reason, @PathVariable("id") Long number)
```